# XPath relative to variable's location in source document

Tags: xslt, xpath

When iterating through the nodes in a node-set variable I want an XPATH 1.0 expression that returns all ancestors of a node (e.g., of $myVariable[7]) -- not the ancestors in the node-set variable, but ancestors in the original document.

I thought one of these would work, but neither does.

```
select="//*[generate-id()=generate-id($myVariable[7])]/ancestor::*"
select="id(generate-id($myVariable[7]))/ancestor::*"
```

Am I close?

**Edit:** It's not central to my question, but I had `//ancestor`; that extra slash is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you open to non-xsl solutions involving Xalan extension functions, for instance (if you're transforming this with Java)? Or what transformation technology are you using?

Comment: The transformation is being done in a browser, so XSLT 1.0 with only the node-set extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your expression**:

```
//*[generate-id()=generate-id($myVariable[7])]/ancestor::*
```

**is correct**.

The reason it is "not working" may be due to the fact that `$myVariable[7]` doesn't contain what you are expecting.

**Here is a simple complete example using the above expression and producing the expected. correct results**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="myVariable"
      select="/*/*/*/*/num"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select=
  "//*[generate-id()
      =
       generate-id($myVariable[7])
       ]
        /ancestor::*
  ">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <nums>
                <num>01</num>
                <num>02</num>
                <num>03</num>
                <num>04</num>
                <num>05</num>
                <num>06</num>
                <num>07</num>
                <num>08</num>
                <num>09</num>
                <num>10</num>
            </nums>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the names of all ancestors of `$myVariable[7]`) is produced**:

```
a
b
c
nums
```

Comment: You were right. I had created the variable not with select but with copy-of, so it wasn't the original node after all. Thanks Dimitre! You got me looking in the right place. +1, Q answered.